# Facebook custom story - map shows up in timeline activity log but on on newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a facebook custom story using the open graph api. I have gotten approval for my story and my action.

I have a story that posts some text along with a map with one point highlighted on the map. I can post the story successfully and it shows up correctly on my timeline/activity log. But when I go to my newsfeed, I can see the story, but the map just shows up as a blank square. I didn't use an og:image tag in my object so it's not like a random image is covering up my map.

Here is the link to my object with the meta tags: http://www.buddyup.mobi/api/fb_object/status/255/

Here is the link to my newsfeed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDqE8.jpg (The stories are the second item in my list)

Here are the stories in my activity log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEGQz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the Open Graph section for your app in the developer center, click on your story. On that page, there's a button that says "edit attachments". Change the layout there from "item" to "map".

Comment: I already did that. The map shows up in my timeline correctly, but on my newsfeed the map is just a blank square.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem at the moment, and as far as I can tell, it is due to Facebook being unable to properly read and/or display some of the provided fields. Which means that you can see the event in your activity log, but not on your own page, or news feed.

I suggest that you double-check the arguments you pass to the server when you post the map.